# Did Rudyard Kipling describe any drink as "from the clippings and shavings of angels' wings"?

Tags: quotes

Use any search engine with the search query '"from the clippings and shavings of angels' wings" Kipling' and you will find many results. [For](https://gmdist.com/blog/agwa) [example](https://www.pinterest.es/pin/691372980265399741/):

> Rudyard Kipling described the powerful elixir as being made "from the clippings and shavings of angels wings", but ...
>
> ... with Rudyard Kipling going as far as to state that they were made "from the clippings and shavings of angels' wings".

And from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agwa_de_Bolivia):

> ... including Rudyard Kipling, who described the drink as being made "from the clippings and shavings of angels' wings"

All search results are modern, so I will accept the answer that presents the earliest instance of the quote. I will also provide a bounty to the answer that identifies the originator of the quote.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that quote was twisted from Kipling's book [*Debits and Credits*](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0603771h.html):

> There was, too, a bottle beyond most known sizes, marked black on
>   red, with a date. Monsieur Voiron opened it, and we drank to the
>   health of my car. The velvety, perfumed liquor, between fawn and
>   topaz, neither too sweet nor too dry, creamed in its generous glass.
>   But I knew no wine composed of the **whispers of angels' wings**, the
>   breath of Eden and the foam and pulse of Youth renewed. So I asked
>   what it might be. 'It is champagne,' he said gravely. 'Then what have
>   I been drinking all my life?' 'If you were lucky, before the War, and
>   paid thirty shillings a bottle, it is possible you may have drunk one
>   of our better-class tisanes.' 'And where does one get this?' 'Here, I
>   am happy to say. Elsewhere, perhaps, it is not so easy. We growers
>   exchange these real wines among ourselves.'

I'll note that Kipling seems to have been quite fond of the phrase "angels' wings" -- he used it a number of times in his writing.  So it is possible (though somewhat unlikely) that he used "clippings and shavings from angels' wings" in another work.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Did you find it because you personally read Kipling? I assume you used kipling "angels' wings" as the search query.

Comment: @BarryHarrison - I found it because of Google.

Comment: Do you have some timeframe as to when the quote originated?

Comment: Alas, Gutenberg doesn't include a publication date.  But no doubt the book is discussed elsewhere.

Comment: A quick Google shows 1926 as the first publication date.

Comment: R. Hicks Thanks for the answer; I meant the quote, as in the falsified version of Kipling's words.

Comment: I'm thinking I ran across something from the 60s, but I'm not seeing it now.

Comment: Oh, too bad:( It would've been great.